# I can't add some of elements in Python

Tags: python, loops, infinite

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []
for x in start_list:
    square_list.append(start_list.append(x**2))
    square_list.sort()
    print square_list
```

I want to add `start_list`'s elements and their sqrt in `square_list`. But it'll be infinite loop. (I guess, it happened in `(start_list.append(x**2)` ) How can i fix it?

Comment: For that `start_list` how should `square_list` look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.append(start_list.append(x**2))` call should, if I understand what you're going for, not actually be `append(append())` but just a lookup. Since you're iterating over your list items, the `x` value is the value you want to append to square_list.

```
for x in start_list:
    square_list.append(x**2)
```

However, the list comprehension technique is probably the 'righter' answer, as it's Pythonic and excellent.

Comment: It's the answer that  i need. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Never alter a list while iterating it. Use list comprehension instead, like this

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
print [x**2 for x in start_list]
# [25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

Actually, you are doing something like this

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
for item in start_list:
    start_list.append(item ** 2)
```

Lets put some `print` statements and understand what happens when you execute the code

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
for item in start_list:
    start_list.append(item ** 2)
    print len(start_list), start_list
    if len(start_list) == 15:
        break
```

**Output**

```
6 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25]
7 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9]
8 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1]
9 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4]
10 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
11 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16, 625]
12 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16, 625, 81]
13 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16, 625, 81, 1]
14 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16, 625, 81, 1, 16]
15 [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16, 625, 81, 1, 16, 256]
```

You are basically growing the list on every iteration by appending to it. That is why your program is in infinite loop.

Comment: Never say never; but you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought its never good to change the elements while iterating them :(

Comment: Again, if you understand what happens, you can still alter the list while iterating. You just need to know how that interacts with the iterator used by `for`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I explained a bit with an example. Does this look okay?

Comment: Why did you use "x**2 for x in start_list"? I didnt understand it.

Comment: @user3433320 It is called [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Python will iterate the `start_list` and on each iteration, value of `x` will be squared and a new list will be created with all the squared values.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that I think `.append()` returns `None`, so you aren't really appending anything to `square_list` when you do:

```
square_list.append(start_list.append(x**2))
```

Thought it might help solve your problem in addition to thefortheye's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `start_list.append(x**2)` will be `None`, so the element in square_list will be `[None, None, None, ...]`, and because you append item to `start_list` during every iteration, so it will get an infinite loop.

I think what you want to do would like this:

```
l = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
l += [x**2 for x in l]
l.sort()
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# without changing the code much
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []
for x in start_list.copy():
    square_list.append(x**2) # appending returns a None value rather the appended value 
    start_list.append(x ** 2) # not sure why you want to append the root into the start list
    square_list.sort() # sort square_list
    print square_list

# better way of doing it
start_list [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = [ x ** 2 for x in start_list]
print square_list
```

If you want to print it like it is in a for loop you could do `[(square_list.sort(), print(square_list[0: x+1])) for x in range(len(square_list))]` but I think it only works in python 3 since print is  a function and not a statement like in python 2(as far as I know.)